# Problems overloading Groovy comparison operators

Tags: groovy, comparison, operator-overloading

I am building an analytic application using Groovy and require very forgiving math operators regardless of data format.  I achieve this through operator overloading, in many cases improving (in my case) on the default Groovy type flexibility.  As an example, I need 123.45f + "05" to equal 128.45f.  By default Groovy downgrades to String and I get 123.4505.

In most cases my overloading works very well, but not for comparison operators.  I've followed a couple of discussions on this, but I'm not getting to an answer and I'm looking for ideas. I recognize that the goal is to overload compareTo() (vs. something like lessThan), but Groovy seems to ignore this and instead attempts its own smart comparison - e.g. DefaultTypeTransformation.compareTo(Object left, Object right), which fails on mixed types.

Unfortunately this is a must have for me, because improperly comparing two values compromises the whole solution and I don't have control over some of the data types being analyzed (e.g. vendor data structures).

For example, I need the following to work:

```
Float f = 123.45f;
String s = "0300";

Assert.assertTrue( f < s );
```

I have many permutations of these, but my attempt to overload includes (let's just assume my JavaTypeUtil does what I need if I can get Groovy to call it):

```
// overloads on startup, trying to catch all cases
Float.metaClass.compareTo = {
    Object o -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, o)  }

Float.metaClass.compareTo = {
    String s -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, s)  }

Object.metaClass.compareTo = {
    String s -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, s) }

Object.metaClass.compareTo = {
    Object o -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, o) }
```

When I try the above test, none of these are called and instead I get:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
at java.lang.Float.compareTo(Float.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:585)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareTo(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:540)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareTo(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:690)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareLessThan(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:710)
at com.modelshop.datacore.generator.GroovyMathTests.testMath(GroovyMathTests.groovy:32)
```

Debugging through I see that the < operator goes right to ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareLessThan(), and the implementation of that seems to ignore the overloaded compareTo() here:

In DefaultTypeTransformations.java:584 (2.4.3)

```
        if (!equalityCheckOnly || left.getClass().isAssignableFrom(right.getClass())
                || (right.getClass() != Object.class && right.getClass().isAssignableFrom(left.getClass())) //GROOVY-4046
                || (left instanceof GString && right instanceof String)) {
            Comparable comparable = (Comparable) left;
            return comparable.compareTo(right);          // <--- ***
        }
```

In a desperate attempt, I've also tried to overload compareLessThan, but I'm grasping now, I don't know that there's any way to jump in front of the < mapping in Groovy.

```
        Float.metaClass.compareLessThan << {
            Object right -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, right) < 0 }
        Float.metaClass.compareLessThan << {
            String right -> JavaTypeUtil.compareTo(delegate, right) < 0 }
```

Any thoughts on a work-around?   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Part of it is you need to include `static`, like this

```
Float.metaClass.static.compareTo = { String s -> 0 }
```

This makes `f.compareTo(s)` work, but the `<` operator still won't work.  This is a [known limitation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1889).  The only operators that can be overloaded are mentioned in the [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading).  Possibly you could do a custom AST to change all those operators to a `compareTo()`.

But this isn't the whole story.  `f <=> s` also doesn't work, despite `<=>` delegating to `compareTo()`.  I believe this is because `Float` doesn't implement `Comparable<Object>` or `Comparable<String>`, only `Comparable<Float>`.  Although I'm not sure where exactly in the chain Groovy makes the decision not to use that method, you can see it's not limited to Groovy's math classes.  This also doesn't work

```
Foo.metaClass.compareTo = { String s -> 99 }
new Foo() <=> ''

class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    int compareTo(Foo o) {
        0
    }
}
```

I think Groovy is doing some pre-parsing validation that's preventing the metaclass stuff from working.  Whatever validation it's doing definitely inspects the interfaces implemented, because this fails for a different reason

```
Foo.metaClass.compareTo = { String s -> 99 }
new Foo() <=> ''

class Foo {
    int compareTo(Foo o) {
        0
    }
}
```

In both of these examples, replacing `<=>` with `compareTo()` works.

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046703/groovy-metaclass) a couple times [before](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/utilizing-comparison-operators-between-types-via-metaclass-td5717609.html), but I haven't seen a good explanation for why.  You might try asking on the user [mailing list](http://groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html).  I'm sure Jochen or Cedric would be able to explain why.

Comment: Thank you.  Hmm, not sure I get the static.  f.compareTo(s) actually works as I had implemented, it was just the <...   Seems a simple fix in Groovy to not use the native Comparitor.compareTo when it's overloaded.  Thanks for the suggestion on the user forum, I will try.

Comment: By "works" I mean this `Float.metaClass.static.compareTo = { String s -> 0 };    Float f = 7.0f;    String s = 'str';    assert f.compareTo(s) == 0`, which is closer, but still not what you wanted.

Comment: A the Jochen Keegan mentioned I can give you more details. The call to compareTo is more or less done with Java method calling logic, so the meta class version is not seen. Additionally `DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck` will check the types of the operands to be compatible - for A.compareTo(B), that A is a subclass of B. We had to add this, because of exceptions a compareTo might throw. Unlike equals compareTo is not required to accept a type that does not fit. And people didn't like a<b throwing type exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I guess the point is that your `compareTo` closure is expecting an `Object`; so when you invoke `compareTo` with a `String`, your closure doesn't get called at all.

I can only think of the following; being precise when specifying closure input parameter type:

```
Float.metaClass.compareTo = { Integer n -> aStaticHelperMethod(n) }
Float.metaClass.compareTo = { String s -> aStaticHelperMethod(s) }
Float.metaClass.compareTo = { SomeOtherType o -> aStaticHelperMethod(o) }
```

Comment: Thanks - I had hit all the permutations  Float -> Object, Float -> String, Object -> Object, Object -> String.